# Given the Generator Matrix of a Continuous-Time-Markov-Chain, find long-term probability of visiting state B if starting in state A

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

$Q=\left(\begin{matrix}  -2 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & -3 & 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 2 & -4 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 &-6  \end{matrix} \right)$

In the state space ${1, 2, 3, 4}$, find the long-term probability  of visiting state 3, for the chain starting in state 2.

I understand the idea should involve making state  3 an  absorbing state, but  I'm not quite sure how to do that for a CTMC. My textbook offers that  if $q_i=0$ for some i, then i  is an absorbing state, where $q_i$ refers to the  entry [3,3], for state 3. But if I  make it 0, I can neither exponentiate to find a stationary  distribution nor  find the inverse of the negative matrix,  V=$-P^-1$,  and do rowsums.

Comment: There are no absorbing states in this Markov chain...

Comment: What do you mean by the "long-term probability of visiting state $3$"? Do you mean "the probability of *ever* visiting state $3$" (which is the interpretation relevant to absorbing states, but which should be $1$ for any ergodic MC) or "the fraction of time spent visiting state $3$" (which becomes a question of finding the limiting distribution)?